# Passport laravel createToken Personal access client not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

After setup of passport, I have configured and created a controller to manage Register-Login- and - access to a resource for a general external post request. I do not need for a specific client. But when I try to create a token in the registration or in the login:

```
$tokenObj=$user->createToken('APPLICATION')->accessToken;
```

The error is:

> RuntimeException: Personal access client not found. Please create one. in file
>   C:\xampp7.1\htdocs\passport\vendor\laravel\passport\src\ClientRepository.php
>   on line 94
>       Stack trace:
>       1. RuntimeException->() C:\xampp7.1\htdocs\passport\vendor\laravel\passport\src\ClientRepository.php:94
>         2. Laravel\Passport\ClientRepository->personalAccessClient() C:\xampp7.1\htdocs\passport\vendor\laravel\passport\src\PersonalAccessTokenFactory.php:71

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You have to create access clients first. It is documented [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#creating-a-personal-access-client). An access client it not the same than a user token, you can have one access client and many users with different passwords and tokens.

Comment: For Laravel 9.x:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport#creating-a-personal-access-client

Answer (score 154):

for me it solved by running

```
php artisan passport:install
```

because it have been happened after refreshing my database.

Comment: Is there a way of running this command automatically after refreshing the database?

Answer (score 46):

In addition to the namelivia's comment. As Laravel doc says:

> Before your application can issue personal access tokens, you will
>   need to create a personal access client. You may do this using the
>   passport:client command with the --personal option. If you have
>   already run the passport:install command, you do not need to run this
>   command:

```
php artisan passport:client --personal
```

But if you did not run the command:

```
php artisan passport:install
```

You should run it first.

Comment: If your not worried about the name, just use `php artisan passport:client --personal --no-interaction`

Answer (score 14):

After running the command

```
php artisan passport:client --personal
```

and give you this prompt

```
 What should we name the personal access client? [Artisan Personal Access Client]:
```

don't worry just type in any name and press the enter key.

Comment: If your not worried about the name, just use `php artisan passport:client --personal --no-interaction`

Answer (score 8):

should I call

```
php artisan passport:install
```

every time I run

```
php artisan:migrate
```

there is a way to do it properly?

Comment: I think you only need to run ```php artisan passport:install --force``` after you run ```php artisan migrate:fresh```.

Answer (score 7):

## The Traits

There're sometimes confusions with the Traits for the User Model.

Sanctum and Passport came with the same Trait, called `HasApiToken`.

You may require to change the namespace in the user model from:

from

```php
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
```

to

```php
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
```

## Testing with PAC

When implementing unit test, you may create a test to create a `personal-access-client` too:

> In case you hash your secrets in your database, you should set `Passport::$hashesClientSecrets` to `false` in your test-cases if you need the unhashed password

```php
use RefreshDatabase

/** @test */
public function can_create_a_personal_access_client()
{
    Passport::$hashesClientSecrets = false;

    $this->artisan(
        'passport:client', 
        ['--name' => config('app.name'), '--personal' => null]
    )->assertSuccessful();


    $this->assertDatabaseCount(PersonalAccessClient::class,1);
}
```

Because we use the `RefreshDatabase` trait, it's usefull to create a helper trait for other tests that may require a `personal-access-client`:

```php
<?php

namespace Tests;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Testing\TestResponse;

trait Helper
{
    protected function createPersonalClient()
    {
        Passport::$hashesClientSecrets = false;

        $this->artisan(
            'passport:client',
            ['--name' => config('app.name'), '--personal' => null]
        );

        // use the query builder instead of the model, to retrieve the client secret
        return DB::table('oauth_clients')
            ->where('personal_access_client','=',true)
            ->first();
    }
}
```

Now, you can re-use the class for other PAT-Tests:

```php
use RefreshDatabase, Helper;

/** @test */
public function can_issue_a_personal_access_token()
{
    $this->createPersonalClient();

    $user = User::factory()->create()->createToken('test');
    
    $this->assertInstanceOf(PersonalAccessTokenResult::class, $user);

    $this->assertObjectHasAttribute('accessToken', $user);
    
    $this->assertObjectHasAttribute('token', $user);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment! So little guides for laravel with appropriate test suites. It seems very few people do use TDD for laravel, what a shame. Also you should add use Laravel\Passport\Passport;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB; in your Helper file to make it work.

Answer (score 6):

Simply run this command

```
php artisan passport:install --force
```

Answer (score 2):

i had the same error over and over again but i didn't how to reproduce it, but i figured it out why.
when you execute `php artisan passport:install`, it stores the two clients IDs in the database after the **migrate** command, but if you **fresh migrate** again, it's obvious you'll lose those two previous IDs, this is why this error was shown after executing the install command.

**UPDATE**
`php artisan passport:install -f` will force recreating the IDs for the new migrated database.